# large string at javascript in order to attach email.

Tags: javascript, html

I need to attach large textarea content to mail with following code.

```
location.href="mailto:a@example.com?subject=example&body="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("listbox").value);
```

However there is a limit length for textarea characters when it exceeds, it doesn't work. I tried with variable and attach to email; however again variables have limits.
How can I attach large strings to an email?
Thanks for help...

Comment: You're likely reaching the URL length limit.

Comment: For more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers Unfortunately there are no ways around this without using your web server to send the email.

Comment: It makes everything more difficult. Thank you very much for information...

Comment: Could you use POST somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do with a POST request:

```
<form action="mailto:youremail@domain.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Email subject">
  <input type="hidden" name="Body" value="Email body">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Of course you can do this in js as well. By creating the DOM structure dynamically and sybmitting the form.

Comment: Thanks for advice; however it didn't change anything. Again when the text is too long submit button doesn't work.

Comment: If your text is that long (probably about 1.5k) there is no workaround. This is a limitation in the HTTP specification, which is in effect even though you never leave your local computer.

Comment: ok. I understood there is no way around for long texts. I will set this answer as my accepted answer.